# Creating 32 bit electron app on 64 bit Windows computer

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

Creating my first Electron app, following Feronato [tutorial](https://www.emanueleferonato.com/2020/10/06/turn-your-html5-games-into-desktop-applications-using-electron-and-distribute-them-part-1-windows/) Part 1. This places Electron as developmental dependency using `npm install --save-dev electron`. Building on 64 bit Windows computer, this results in 64 bit Electron app. Also, would like to build a 32 bit app.

(1) Can I change the code to add --ia32 flag to create a 32 bit app?
For example, `npm install --save-dev --ia32 electron`
(2) Do I need to separately install Electron 32 on computer?

So far have not been able to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial doesn't really use a proper Electron distribution build procedure (it just says you'd copy bits and pieces around by hand, which is icky and boring in the long run).

The [Electron docs on distribution](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/application-distribution) say you'd likely use e.g. electron-forge, electron-builder, or electron-packager. All of those tools seem to support setting the target `architecture` (or `arch` for short).

Anyway, if you really do want to do things by hand, follow that distribution page, read the [manual distribution](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/application-distribution#manual-distribution) section, then find [the win32-ia32 package on the Github releases page](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v17.1.1) and work with that...

Comment: Thank you. Any preferences between forge, builder, packager?

Comment: Well, forge seems to be preferred by the tutorial: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs%2Ftutorial%2Fquick-start.md#package-and-distribute-your-application